# throw new Exception statement not working in MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to import details from an access database into my sql application database.  I have a check to make sure that it has imported all the rows, and if it hasn't then I want it to stop the process and throw an error.

However, despite it going into the correct function, and hitting the "throw" line, it doesn't throw the error, and instead just carries on with the process.

Should this code block not work?

```
AccessRepository details = new AccessRepository();
if (numRows != details.GetDetailsRowCount(periodsInFreq, payDate))
{
   throw new DataException("Some data is missing from the Details table (only " + numRows.ToString() + " rows) - Please try again.  If this problem persists, please contact the system administrator");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that the exception is not caught elsewhere?

Comment: Isnt the exception thrown not hitting the client side? Guess it should haev been caught some where else.

Comment: Yes you're right actually.  It was appearing in a different catch statement further down the page.  Good thinking - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Varun and Zenwalker.

It turned out I had some nested catch statements which were cancelling each other out.  I've since taken out the nested try/catches out and the errors now make a lot more sense.

Thanks